# Kepler.gl Map Center Default set to 0,0

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, kepler.gl

Anybody using Kepler.gl here? Need to know how to modifiy kepler's map center dynamic? Now when I load data, the map by default points to 0,0 lag-lng

Answer (score 0):

If you've written your own load-data-modal (similar to the [demo-app](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/tree/master/examples/demo-app) in the kepler.gl git repo) and injected it to the app, you can use the updateMap function to set the map state. At the top of your load-data-modal.js, add the following line:

```
import {updateMap} from 'kepler.gl/actions';
```

In order to dispatch the action, you then need to add a dispatch function to the component. One way to do that is using redux connect:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
```

Then at the bottom of your file, replace the export with

```
const mapStateToProps = state => state
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => ({
    dispatch,
    keplerGlDispatch: forwardTo("map", dispatch)
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(LoadDataModal);
```

Once you've done that, you can use updateMap to change the map state and update the lat lon as follows:

```
this.props.keplerGlDispatch(updateMap({"latitude": 39.738756,"longitude": -105.023357}));
```

Comment: Thanks alot :), I will try it out.